# Powershell command no longer working - only running as an administrator

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm not really good at PS so I decided to ask for some advice.

I have a VBA script that uses `Get-DhcpServerv4Lease` in a PS command to query the DHCP server (as a domain admin user) for a given Scope and arrange the data returned into Excel.

```
strCommand = "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe start-job -credential <domain>\" & TheAdminUser & " -ScriptBlock{Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName '<DHCP server>' -ScopeId " & TheScope & "} | wait-job | receive-job"

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)
strOutput = WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll
```

The script was working perfectly before, now for some unknown reason it's no longer functioning.

Tried to manually run the command in PS and realized it is now only working if I run PS as administrator (works even as local admin), else it returns the following error:

```
[localhost] An error occurred while starting the background process. Error reported: The directory name is invalid.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2147467259,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Any advice what might be the problem or where could I start looking for a solution?

Update:

In the meantime I found a different workaround that fixes the original code I used.

Adding `[environment]::CurrentDirectory='C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0';` makes it run again without the error.

```
strCommand = "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe "[environment]::CurrentDirectory='C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0';start-job -credential <domain>\" & TheAdminUser & " -ScriptBlock{Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName '<DHCP server>' -ScopeId " & TheScope & "} | wait-job | receive-job"
```

*The answers were very useful, maybe alternative workarounds for others, and got me closer to understand Powershell better.*

Comment: Nice job finding the workaround - that it is the _process-level_ working directory that is the problem hadn't occurred to me (unfortunately, the workaround isn't effective in `pwsh` (PowerShell (Core), as of v7.2.0-preview.8). That this solved your problem implies that you don't actually need _elevation_, right? I've added an explanation of the workaround to my answer and have clarified the elevation aspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any advice what might be the problem

The problem is **a bug in the [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) cmdlet** that affects both Windows PowerShell (v5.1, the latest and final version) and PowerShell (Core) v6+ (albeit with different symptoms, still as of PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.8 - see [GitHub issue #7172](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7172)).

**In *Windows PowerShell*, the background process uses a (fixed) working directory in the *calling* user's home-directory tree (the `Documents` folder), which the user whose credentials are passed to `-Credential` is not allowed to access**, causing the error you saw - and there's no way to specify a *different* working directory.

- `Start-Job -Credential` *does* work *if your session is elevated*, i.e. running with admin privileges, in which case the *target* user's `Documents` folder is switched to. Given that the standard `runas.exe` utility can invoke commands as a different user even from *non-elevated* sessions, there should be no need for this requirement, however.
- Also - as you have discovered yourself - there is a **workaround**:

  - If you explicitly **set the *process-level* working directory (which is distinct from PowerShell's) to one the target user is permitted to access**, `Start-Job -Credential` works; for instance, you can use `C:\` or `$env:SYSTEMROOT\Windows32` (the latter is what `runas.exe` uses); a quick example (replace `otheruser` with the username of interest):

    ```sh
    [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = 'C:\' # set process-level working dir.
    Start-Job -Credential (Get-Credential otheruser) { whoami } | 
      Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
    ```

***PowerShell (Core)*** now makes the background process inherit the caller's working directory (which the caller could set to a directory accessible by the target user) and also has a `-WorkingDirectory` parameter, but neither approach solves the problem with `-Credential` as of PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview - even if you run *with elevation* (and the above workaround doesn't help either).

Based on the update to your question, it seems the workaround solved your problem, implying that you do *not* require the operation running with the domain user identity to be *elevated*; the following may still be of interest for use cases where elevation *is* required.

---

***If* you need to run the operation that uses a different user identity *with elevation* (with admin privileges):**

Launching an *elevated* (run as admin) process is something `Start-Job -Credential` *fundamentally cannot* provide.

**The only (PowerShell-native) way to launch an elevated process is via [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `-Verb RunAs`**.

- Note: Using `Start-Process` means that the launched process' *output* cannot be captured directly by the caller, and instead requires sending the output to *files* via the `--RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError` parameters, which the caller - assuming termination of the process is waited for - can later read.

Therefore, try the following:

```sh
strCommand = "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -c Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs powershell.exe \""-c Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName '<DHCP server>' -ScopeId " & TheScope & "\"""
```

Note:

- *Another* call to `powershell.exe` is required, launched with elevation (`-Verb RunAs`), synchronously (`-Wait`), which then performs the `Get-DhcpServerv4Lease` call in the foreground.

  - Because `Start-Process -Verb RunAs` invariably launches the process in a *new* window, you may want to hide that window too, by adding `-WindowStyle Hidden` to the `Start-Process` call. Conversely, if you *do* want to see that window, you may want to hide the *intermediate* window that launches the elevated one, using VBA features.
  - Note: I've added `-c` (`-Command`) to the [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) calls for conceptual clarity; while this parameter is *implied* in `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell), in `pwsh.exe`, the PowerShell (Core) equivalent, the default is now `-f` (`-File`).
  - Also note the need to `\`-escape the embedded `"` chars. (escaped for VBA as `""`), so that the PowerShell CLI *retains* them as part of the command to execute after command-line argument parsing.
- As with your original attempt, this will *prompt* for a password, and if the calling user doesn't have administrative privileges *in principle*, an administrator's *username* will have to be entered too. Note that this prompt cannot be prevented (unless you turn [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) off, which is ill-advised).

  - **The admin username to use for elevation *cannot* be passed**, because `-Verb RunAs` is mutually exclusive with `-Credential`. The logic of `-Verb RunAs` is such that if the current user is an admin user (in principle), *it* is *invariably* used for the elevated session, and you're only presented with a Yes/No confirmation dialog. Thus, if you need a *different* admin user, such as a *domain* admin, this won't work - see below. (Only if the calling user is *not* an admin user does the UAC prompt ask for a username and password explicitly).

---

**If you need to run the elevated session with a *given* admin user account**:

Unfortunately, this requires an even more deeply nested command, with additional pitfalls:

- In essence, you need to first call `Start-Process -Credential` to create an (of necessity) *non-elevated* session with the target user, which then allows you to call `Start-Process -Verb RunAs` to create an *elevated* session for that user.

  - **Caveat**: This **requires you to answer *two* prompts**: first, you need to enter the password to start the non-elevated session for the admin user, and then you need to answer the Yes/No UAC prompt to confirm the intent to start an elevated session for that user.
- A `Set-Location C:\` command is incorporated, to ensure that the working directory is valid for the target user (in the initial non-elevated session).
- Using `Start-Process -Wait` in order to wait for termination of a process started with a different user (`-Credential`) inexplicably fails due lack of permissions when invoked from a non-elevated session; the workaround is to use `(Start-Process -PassThru ...).WaitForExit()`.
- To simplify quoting, only `'...'` quoting (escaped as `''...''` in the nested call) is used - therefore, the commands themselves mustn't contain `'` chars.

This leads to the following monstrosity.

```vb
' Assumes that the following variables are defined:
'   TheAdminUser, TheComputerName, TheScope
strCommand = "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -c Set-Location C:\; (Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden -PassThru -Credential " & TheAdminUser & " powershell.exe ' -c Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '' -c Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName " & TheComputerName & " -ScopeId " & TheScope & " '' ').WaitForExit()"
```

Note: For troubleshooting, precede the `-c` argument(s) with `-noexit` to keep the PowerShell session(s) open.

---

**Alternative, with prior setup**:

As [Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn) points out, one way to allow a non-admin user to execute a preconfigured operation - only - with administrative privileges is to set up a *scheduled task* that runs with admin credentials and performs the desired operation, which non-admin users can then *invoke on demand*.

This would obviate the need for a password altogether, but be sure that the operation is truly safe for non-admin users to perform.

**Note**: Having a scheduled task run by a non-admin user / from a non-elevated process can *fail* under certain circumstances - though it *does* work in the scenario at hand, according to Joel; as he notes in reference to [this Server Fault post](https://serverfault.com/q/881144/176094):

> I think part of the problem was trying to run as SYSTEM rather than a specific privileged user in elevated mode. It also talks about contexts like SCCM and startup, where certain registry keys are not available, and the powershell code to invoke the task may also have changed.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use `-WindowStyle Hidden` because Trend Micro gives me an alert and closes the process.  
After removing it, the command is executed with only one prompt (possibly because I already have local admin rights).  
The script now shows the preferred data (in a different format than before) in the PS window, however nor in CMD or in VBA is the data returned into the variable or in the CMD window.

I have updated my question with an additional part of my code, maybe it clarifies what's going on.

Comment: Found a workaround, included in my question as well.

Comment: @Divin3, again, nice job on the workaround, which I've included in the answer. As an inconsequential aside: would `-WindowStyle Minimized` work? (Sadly, it _steals focus_, though - see [GitHub issue #7790](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7790)). In addition to including your workaround and explaining that you don't need elevation, I've added a note on how to _capture output_ with `Start-Process` (in short: you have to redirect to _files_); I hadn't paid attention to the fact that  your command indeed relays the output from the `Get-DhcpServerv4Lease` call.

Comment: After reverting to my original code, `-WindowStyle Minimized` is no longer working
`Start-Job : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'WindowStyle'.`
Out of curiosity I tried your code again using your suggestion and the antivirus no longer alerts.

Comment: I also noticed that your version of code changes the format I get the info back from the server. My original method returns results sort as a group, and yours as a list.

Comment: @Divin3: Thanks for checking `-WindowStyle Minimized`, but I meant it to be applied to _Start-Process_, not Start-Job (the latter has no such parameter and doesn't need it, as jobs by definition run windowless, invisibly). I was merely curious whether you would get an anti-virus alert for it too. If your `Start-Job` solution works, i.e. if you don't need actual elevation, just a different user identity, it is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @Divin3: As for different outputs: That's difficult to unpack in a comment, but note that using `Start-Job` adds additional properties to the result, related to the remoting infrastructure, and that in most cases there is loss of type fidelity - that is, you get _emulations_ of the original output-object types back. With `Start-Process`, running the PowerShell CLI outputs _formatted text_ by default, though you can request the same XML-based serialization format that `Start-Job` uses behind the scenes with `-OutputFormat Xml`. From a file, you can deserialize with `Import-CliXml`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `Start-Process -RunAs` for the `powershell.exe` command and it will elevate. Note that this ***will*** trigger UAC if the vBA process isn't already elevated.

The kicker is that if you are trying to self-elevate from a *different* process, `Start-Process` is a PowerShell cmdlet so you will need to basically run PowerShell to run another elevated PowerShell session. The command will look something like this:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '-Command ""YOUR ELEVATED CODE HERE""'"
```

You can test this with the following command in Command Prompt that will output "hello", wait for a key-press, then exit:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '-Command ""echo hello; cmd /c pause""'"
```

Note that this is how you would invoke the command from the command line, whether PowerShell or CMD. You may need to tweak the escape sequences if calling from another language.

---

You should also make use of the `-Command` parameter when invoking `powershell.exe` or `pwsh` from somewhere else and want to exit the session once the command is complete, or the `-File` parameter for the same but it's a script.

You also need to make use of the `-Wait` parameter when you call `Start-Process` or else it won't block. This is antithesis to the general executable invocation pattern that non-GUI programs usually don't need the `-Wait` parameter to block until the process exits.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use an `'...'` string to enclose a `-Command` argument if you call via `Start-Process`: Try `Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait powershell.exe '-Command ''Get-Date'''`

Comment: I'm confused; you say it can't be done but then you enclose the following command in single quotes again

Comment: Nvm, I misunderstood what you meant at first. I figured out the correct escape pattern to use, it's.... not fun, escaping sucks

Comment: Indeed, but just to spell it out: Note how my example command, instead of _executing_ `Get-Date`, echoes it _verbatim_, because when the PowerShell CLI is called from _outside_ PowerShell (on Windows), the `'` chars. don't have syntactic function, so what PowerShell ultimately sees as the source code to execute is a single-quoted verbatim string.

Comment: Yep. This is very evident in Command Prompt, but as I almost always work with PowerShell these days, it's a detail I sometimes forget. In any case, I've updated my code with a mouthful of a command.

Comment: I was able to successfully run the command: `strCommand = "powershell.exe -Command ""Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '-Command ""start-job -credential <user> -ScriptBlock{Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName <DHCP Server> -ScopeId 10.190.0.0} | wait-job | receive-job""'"""` 
I see the data being written on a PS window, however it does not return anything into the variable.